# how to insert file name into "to_csv"

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python formula to summarize price in a dataframe.

```
def test(df1,keys=["price"]):
x=df1.groupby(keys).size()
x.to_csv("%s_price.txt" % (df1),sep='\t')
```

I tried as follows.

```
test(df_Example,keys=["price"])
```

I want to put file name (df_Example) into the output file, so I used %s but this did not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: you mean `'df1'`?

Comment: `df1` is a variable referencing a dataframe. The dataframe has no name, and the `str()` conversion of a dataframe is not going to be suitable for a filename (it contains newlines, for starters). Because your *variable name never changes*, you want to just use `"df1_price.txt"`.

Comment: I edited. Please see the edited version. Can I add "df_Example" in the output file?

Comment: I'm guessing you have many DataFrames, and you would like to create a unique file name for each one.  Why not store them in a dictionary where the `key` is the "name" you'd like for your frame, and use that when you write to a file.

Comment: Yes, I have lots of DataFrames. That's a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use f-strings:

```
def test(df1, filename, keys=["price"]):
    x = df1.groupby(keys).size()
    x.to_csv(f"{filename}_price.txt", sep='\t')

test(df_Example, "df_Example.csv", keys=["price"])
```

I think it only works in python 3.6+

Answer (score 1):

I guess the function should be (couldn't edit it):

```
def test(df1,keys=["price"]):
    x=df1.groupby(keys).size()
    x.to_csv("%" % (df1),sep='\t')
```

A way to do it is:

```
def test_updated(df,filename,keys=["price"]):
    x=df.groupby(keys).size()
    filename = "{}s_price.txt".format(filename)
    x.to_csv(filename,sep='\t')
```

Comment: Please note: as posted, this will result in `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`. I would advise double-checking code in the interpreter before posting to avoid errors of this nature.

Comment: @SethMMorton you are completely correct, Thanks will do that from now on!